# 十二支の訓読みと十二生肖について

Tags: readings

I browsed Wikipedia and found that the kunyomi of the earthly branches and those of the corresponding animal zodiac look alike. Still there are some difference, e.g., 子(ね rather than ねずみ) and 巳 (み rather than へび). Does anyone know the origin of the difference? (Especially the 巳/蛇 one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 十二支 was introduced into Japan, there was already zodiac mnemonics established in China, so all kun'yomi are animal names.

- 子【ね】: abbreviation of ねずみ "mouse/rat"
- 卯【う】: abbreviation or original word form (disputed) of うさぎ "rabbit/hare"
- 巳【み】: abbreviation of old word form [へみ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%BF/) "snake" (now へび)
- 亥【い】: original word form い (ゐ) "wild boar" (いのしし literally means "boar-beast")

An interesting case is 未【ひつじ】 = 羊, as sheep are not native in Japan, its Japanese name is reversely taken from the time in a day 未 represents: 1 PM—3 PM. Since this is the afternoon period when the sun goes from above to downward, it is called ひ "sun" + つじ "corner".